# lxml: how to iterate only on the first/second siblings?

Tags: python, iteration, lxml, siblings

I have an html-document of this kind:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <p>
     <dfn>text</dfn>sometext
     **<i>othertext</i>**
     <i>...</i>
     <i>...</i></p>
   <p>
     <dfn>text</dfn>sometext
     **<i>othertext</i>**
     <i>...</i>
     <i>...</i></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I need to parse it so that I could get text from inside each first i-tag, and with respect to dfn's text (I will extract dfn-text finally)
At the moment I this code:

```
tree = etree.parse(filename)
for dfn in tree.iter('dfn'):
   bu = dfn.text
   for sibling in dfn.itersiblings():   
            su = sibling.text
            if su != None and bu != None and re.findall(..,su):
                places.append(bu)
```

This goes through each i-tag, giving me sometimes erroneous output. How can I limit iteration to only first siblings of the dfn?

Comment: Why not simply break out of the `for sibling` loop then?

Comment: and what should I get instead of my for sibling loop?

Comment: I didn't say *instead*. I mean that as soon as you have a match in the `for sibling` loop, use `break` to end the loop and ignore any further siblings.

Comment: aah, ok, I did't get it)) Thank you very much! It seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out of the `itersiblings()` loop when you found your match:

```
for dfn in tree.iter('dfn'):
    bu = dfn.text
    for sibling in dfn.itersiblings():   
        su = sibling.text
        if su != None and bu != None and re.findall(..,su):
            places.append(bu)
            break
```

The `break` statement ends the `for sibling` loop early, and no further siblings are processed. Instead, the outer `for dfn` loop continues with the next `dfn` element.